# how to append the content to existing file in skydrive using livesdk

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, live-sdk

I am using the below code to upload the content on my phone to a file "SavedContent" on my skydrive.

```
App.liveConnectClient.UploadAsync("me/SkyDrive", "SavedContent" , fileStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);

App.liveConnectClient.UploadCompleted += liveConnectClient_UploadCompleted;
```

Instead of overwriting the existing file I  want to append the new content to above file if the file already exists.

The only way I see it is by downloading the content of the file if already exists and then append the new content and upload the file again with overwrite option.
How can I do this using the livesdk ?